# How to clone a private repo without providing user credentials?

Tags: git

We have a private repo, which we want to clone inside a remote server via Ansible. The steps I followed is:

```
ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
git clone https://<username>:<password>@github.com/EpisourceLLC/Cypher.git /home/ubuntu/Cypher/
```

Here, I am entering my personal username and password. Is there any way I can clone the repo without providing mine or anyone's credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Make an account in Github, and call it something like `Remote Server`. Give it readonly permissions.
2. Install an SSH key into this account, and keep the private key in the server.
3. Clone the repository in the remote server using `git://` url.

That will make the servers able to access the repository using the ssh credentials. It will use the private's server key stored, instead of prompting user-password.

Comment: Creating the server on the fly [AWS Lambda].  Any other way I can do it?

Comment: I don't know what are the exact problem by using AWS, but as far as you can **either** generate an ssh key and install into Github account **or** copy and paste the same key into all servers, you will have access from every server.